# How to persist to both localStorage and sessionStorage at the same time using redux-persist?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-persist

I'm implementing a login form using `react`, `redux` and `redux-persist`. Login API is ready from back-end team. The form has a "remember me" checkbox and I want to persist JWT auth token from login response.

What I think is the right way to implement "remember me" is this:

- If "remember me" is not checked, token should be persisted to 
  `sessionStorage`. So that when browser is closed, user should login again but does not need login on switching tab or refreshing current page.
- If it is checked, token should be persisted to `localStorage`. User is still logged in even if the browser is closed.

Now I know from our back-end perspective there is only token expiration time.

My first question is if my client side view and approach is correct or not.

If it is, how can I update my persist config based on login "remember me" checkbox?

My current `store.js` is this:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'; 
import rootReducer from './reducers';

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
  whitelist: ['auth'],
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

const store = createStore(persistedReducer);

const persistor = persistStore(store);

export {
  store, persistor
};
```

And it is used here:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from 'js/containers/App';
import { store, persistor } from './store';

const render = Component => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Component store={store} persistor={persistor}/>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  )
};

render(App);

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('js/containers/App', () => {
    const NextApp = require('js/containers/App').default;
    render(NextApp);
  });
}
```

I want to change `persistConfig` based on login form and use `sessionStorage` instead of `localStorage` but it's like store structure is formed here and there is no way to change it in app.

Any idea how to implement this?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can change storage after creating but you can have 2 sub-tree on different storages. So tick/untick "remember me" will save in different trees and make a function to get the token from both sources.

to create sub-tree on difference storage see this
https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist#nested-persists

**Edit**
Adding sample for clarity.

```js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'
import storageSession from 'redux-persist/lib/storage/session'

const rootPersistConfig = { key: 'root', storage, whitelist: ['cart','user'] }; 
const authPersistConfig = { key: 'user', storage:storageSession }; // This is to session storage
const rootReducer = combineReducers({ 
                user: persistReducer(authPersistConfig,userReducer), // user subtree saved in session storage
                cart: cartReducer, 
                directory: directoryReducer, 
                shop: shopReducer }); 
                
export default persistReducer(rootPersistConfig, rootReducer);
```

Comment: I tried it but it didnt work for me


const cartPersistConfig = {
  key: 'cart',
  storage,
  whitelist: ['cart']
}

const authPersistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage:storageSession,
  whitelist: ['user', 'cart']
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  user: persistReducer(authPersistConfig,userReducer),
  cart: cartReducer,
  directory: directoryReducer,
  shop: shopReducer
});

export default persistReducer(cartPersistConfig, rootReducer);

Any idea what i am doing wrong?

Comment: @Zenit 
const rootPersistConfig = { key: 'root', storage, whitelist: ['cart','user'] }; 
const authPersistConfig = { key: 'user', storage:storageSession }; 
const rootReducer = combineReducers({ user: persistReducer(authPersistConfig,userReducer), cart: cartReducer, directory: directoryReducer, shop: shopReducer }); 
export default persistReducer(rootPersistConfig, rootReducer);

Comment: You nailed it Chayne. Thanks a lot.