# How to implement remember me functionality in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-persist

I'm making a simple login signup form with remember me functionality in `react js` along with `redux`, `thunk` and `redux-persist`. When I send correct login details i.e. email and password the api returns a non changing (permanent) access_token.

Expected Functionality:- if remember me is ticked the access token should always be saved so that when ever I revisit the page after closing the browser or when I refresh the page I should be automatically logged in to home page

if remember me is not ticked the access token is stored only till I don't exit the page or I don't close the browser, once browser is closed the access_token is automatically deleted

my approach is:

if - remember me button is ticked then I want to persist the access token (received from api) in local storage

and if- remember me button is not ticked then I want to store the access token in session storage

can someone help me to implement this or correct my approach if it is wrong.

https://github.com/guneethind/login-signup

Login.js

```
>  const Login = () => {
>  const dispatch = useDispatch();
>  const navigate = useNavigate();
>
>  const data = useSelector((state) => state.login);
>
>  const onFinish = (values) => {
>    dispatch(setLoginValues(values));
>  };
>
>  useEffect(() => {
>    if (data?.loginSuccess?.access_token) {
>      message.success("Logged in");
>      navigate("/home");
>    } else if (data?.loginFailed?.status === 401) {
>      message.error(`${data.loginFailed.message}`);
>      navigate("/login");
>      dispatch(setLoginEmpty());
>    }
>  }, [data]);
```

store.js

```
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";


const persistConsif = {
  key: "root",
  storage: storage,
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConsif, reducers);

export const store = createStore(
  persistedReducer,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk))
);

export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
      <App />
    </PersistGate>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: Could you provide all the things you have tried till now? We can then look at that and suggest you changes, if needed.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. You write the code, and if it doesn't work, post it here and we'll help you debug it.

Comment: @AnindyaDey I have added my code

Comment: @BrettDonald I have added my code

Comment: So does it work? If not, what did you expect it to do, and what did you observe instead? Try to see the problem from our point of view. We know nothing about your project. You need to provide enough information about the problem for us to understand it, and you need to explain what you've attempted yourself in your efforts to solve it.

Comment: See @BrettDonald I'm only able to implement the functionality when remember me is ticked using redux-persist i.e. the access_token  is permanently saved in local storage.

Comment: I don't know how to implement the functionality for "when the remember me is unticked"....

Comment: I want help with how to implement the unticked functionality should I use session stored with redux-persist or should I use session cookies...........
my problem is very much similar to this problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56099291/how-to-persist-to-both-localstorage-and-sessionstorage-at-the-same-time-using-re?newreg=dad1492e882042a998b09a4e81dabbd0

Comment: You could look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58032881/13584363. There's a "sessionStorage" (`redux-persist/lib/storage/session`) module which you might use.

Comment: For more info, look at the npm page of redux-persist - https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist#storage-engines

Comment: Asking to help to implement is not appropriate here, I guess. Stackoverflow is not for writing code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally resolved the problem,
I used cookies for when the remember me is unticked
and local storage for when remember me is ticked

here's the code for the same
https://github.com/guneethind/login-signup/tree/cookies-implementaion